# Cannot decide on which English chess term is correct for when a friendly pawn stands in the bishop's way

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

I'm translating a Russian chess article to English and I got stuck at one sentence. It describes the situation when a bishop cannot move because a friendly pawn stands in the bishop's way. In Russian it is "Пешка запирает слона", and almost all Russian books I look into use this phrase. But when I look into English books, they seem to use a large number of different terms for this situation. For example, they use "the pawn locks in the bishop", "the pawn hems in the bishop", "the pawn closes off the bishop", "the pawn restricts the bishop" and "the pawn restrains the bishop". Which of these English terms is the most correct and universally accepted in this case?

Comment: There's a chess stack exchange that might be more help with this, though you may well get an answer here

Comment: The literal translation is _locks_, so that or _blocks_ would be most standard.

Comment: This is absolutely a question for [chess.se] Stack Exchange. Sure, you're writing in English but you're looking for a technical term that only makes sense in the world of chess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about field specific jargon and so should be asked at [chess.se].

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would use the word **blocks**, as was used in an answer on the [Chess Stack Exchange](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/17001/why-is-an-isolated-queen-pawn-so-special/):

> This would not be the case in the Stonewall where the e3 pawn **blocks** the Rook's activity.

Another word that could be used, I suppose – although it might be more of a stretch – is **stymies**:

> the pawn *stymies* the bishop

The word *stymie* means "prevent or hinder the progress of” (NOAD). It’s originally a golfing term, used to describe when prevent or hinder the progress of the situation on the green where a ball obstructs the shot of another player, and the word can be used [as a noun or a verb](https://www.wordnik.com/words/stymie).

At least one chess book uses this word:

> Black can **stymie** White by moving the rook-pawn from a7 to a5.
>
> (from *Weapons of Chess: An Omnibus of Chess Strategies*
> by Bruce Pandolfini)

Comment: And GM Yasser Seirawan uses "blocks" too. Thanx. Didn't expect to get help in a matter of few minutes!!!

Comment: 'blocks' and the other terms in the OP are all appropriate. 'Stymie' is also appropriate, but it has a strange sound to it, almost slang. Use with caution, it might sound unintentionally comical.

Comment: @Mitch - I concur. Moreover, going back to the OP's candidates, I prefer _hems in_ to _closes off_, and _restricts_ over _restrains_, but those might just be personal preferences. Another possibility not yet mentioned is _**impedes**_.

Comment: **Blocks**, yes, or **interferes with**. "Interfere" and "interference" are standardly used and understood in chess to refer to a unit being in the way of a friendly line-piece. "Stymies" is as far as I know not a word with a clear unambiguous meaning in chess. Indeed, in that sentence quoted from Pandolfini, a player stymies a player (rather than a unit stymying a unit).

Comment: What's funny about stymie is the golf rule that created it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you asked for correct, so you should know that all the translations you provided were standard English. I have played chess for twenty years and am quite sure there is no term for said situation. If there is, it’s very rare. Because of such, in English, there is no better word in terms of correctness. Some have particular origins, are phrases or single words but more abstract, etc. To block is indeed the generic word but as you see from the verb to stymie there are even more precise synonyms. Any of them would work and would be correct, of that I am one hundred percent certain. If you want to include style, block would not be the verb to go with, but if you want to include the largest possible audience, block is your best bet.

Comment: I agree with pretty much everything you say here, but it’s worth pointing out that the OP’s question is a fair one. Someone translating a work on chess could write, for example, “The knight is the only piece that can jump over other pieces on the chessboard.” Grammatically, the translator could use just about synonym for _jump_ – such as _hop, leapfrog, vault,_ or _spring_ – but some options may not work as well as others, and a poor choice might even undermine the author’s credibility.

Comment: @j.r.  I agree with your comment but stand behind this answer because it speaks to the original question which was "which is the correct term?" The answer is "in English there is no agreed upon correct term, so the one's given are all correct. 'block' may be the most used". Meanwhile if someone were to ask for the correct term for "jump" in a game of chess, we would agree that the standard term wasn't "leapfrog" or "bounce". The idea being that we do have some "correct" words but this isn't such a case.

Answer (score -1):

Another word to consider could be ***stifles***

- [to prevent something from happening, being expressed, or continuing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stifle)

The pawn *stifles* the bishop's activity.

Comment: Is this term commonly used by chess writers? I used to read quite a lot of chess publications and I don't recall seeing it. (But this would be ten or so years ago, so I may well have forgotten.)